# Talking about something general with clause that happens earlier - past tense or not?

Tags: grammar, tense

Background story: My friend likes to boast about his work achievements a lot.

I want to complain about it to others. Which one below is grammatically correct?

The hard concept for me: I don't know if I should use past tense in this case. Since it is about his regular boasting behavior, it seems correct to use present or present perfect. However, I think past tense can work here too...

> > 01  My friend always boasts about what he **achieves** at work.
> >
> > 02 My friend always boasts about what he **achieved** at work.
> >
> > 03 My friend always boasts about what he **has achieved** at work.
> >
> > 04 My friend always likes to boast about the achievements that he **accomplishes** at work.
> >
> > 05 My friend always likes to boast about the achievements that he **accomplished** at work.
> >
> > 06 My friend always likes to boast about the achievements that he **has accomplished** at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Achieved" and "accomplished" are both past tense. If you use these words, it sounds like your friend is boasting only about something that happened in the past. Even though you say "always boasts" to indicate that he continues to do this, he could still be talking about something that happened in the past.

If you mean to say that he boasts about achievements on an ongoing basis, then you need to use the present tense (he achieves / he accomplishes):

> My friend always boasts about what he achieves/accomplishes at work.

Comment: The present continuous tense should look like this: to be [am, is, are] + **verb [present participle]**, no?